# How to download excel (.xls) file from API in postman?

Tags: rest, postman, rest-client, advanced-rest-client

I have an API endpoint and an Authorization token for that API.

The said API is for `.xls` report download. How can I view the downloaded `.xls` file using (if possible) *Postman*?

If it is not possible using *Postman* what are the other programmatic ways I should be looking for?

Comment: @nbokmans  I want to download .xls file provided by backend
when i use postman, i am not able to view .xls file properly, its all unicodes and special characters. What I need is, If there is any other programmatic way apart from postman for firing an api and downloading .xls file on my pc

Comment: @nbokmans Thanks for reply, it just starts download, it doesn't give any location.

Answer (score 812, accepted):

Try selecting `send and download` instead of `send` when you make the request. (the blue button)

[image: Screenshot showing "Send and Download" button in postman]

https://www.getpostman.com/docs/responses

"For binary response types, you should select `Send and download` which will let you save the response to your hard disk. You can then view it using the appropriate viewer."

Comment: this is definitely not intuitive - thanks for the pointer! Tried **Save Response** but it just saved to **Examples** which wasn't helpful.

Comment: This only downloads the response.json and not the file itself.

Comment: I tried this, and it downloads the raw base64 encoded file as a text file, not as the file itself...

Answer (score 30):

You can Just save the response(pdf,doc etc..) by option on the right side of the response in postman
check this image 
[image: postman save response]

For more Details check this

https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/responses/

Comment: It seems to ok. But there is not Save Response option for GET or POST requests. Should I use **Send and Download** option on Postman?

Comment: for each request, you will get an option to save the response, but as you mentioned you can use the send & save option as well

Answer (score 9):

If the endpoint really is a direct link to the .xls file, you can try the following code to handle downloading:

```
public static boolean download(final File output, final String source) {
    try {
        if (!output.createNewFile()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not create new file!");
        }
        URL url = new URL(source);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        // Comment in the code in the following line in case the endpoint redirects instead of it being a direct link
        // connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        connection.setRequestProperty("AUTH-KEY-PROPERTY-NAME", "yourAuthKey");
        final ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(connection.getInputStream());
        final FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(output);
        fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, 1 << 24);
        fos.close();
        return true;
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

All you *should* need to do is set the proper name for the auth token and fill it in.

Example usage:

```
download(new File("C:\\output.xls"), "http://www.website.com/endpoint");
```

Answer (score 7):

In postman - Have you tried adding the header element 'Accept' as 'application/vnd.ms-excel'

Answer (score 7):

For UI, choose **Send and Download** button instead of **Send** button in Postman:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

In the response section follow these steps:

[image]