# how can receive stream from API using postman?

Tags: stream, postman

API response has stream and text. Postman only can display text response. How do I receive stream file in response using postman?

Comment: I found answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38975718/how-to-download-excel-xls-file-from-api-in-postman). Should click "send and download" rather than send.