# Exporting excel file in postman with laravel api

Tags: php, excel, laravel, api, postman

when I try to send the API request to export the excel file in postman it gives the following respone[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aS3ak.png)

but when I tried the endpoint in the browser the excel file is downloaded.

what is the best way to test the api to export the excel file in laravel

Answer (score 2):

see this:
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38975718/how-to-download-excel-xls-file-from-api-in-postman)

Try selecting send and download instead of send when you make the request. (the blue button)

https://www.getpostman.com/docs/responses

"For binary response types, you should select Send and download which will let you save the response to your hard disk. You can then view it using the appropriate viewer."